# Nordvpn blocking internet traffic despite being disabled

Tags: vpn, iptables

I have a problem with NordVPN on Debian Buster:

1. I've been using `iptables` on my Linux PC, but after disconnecting from NordVPN, the IPtables rules still persist and I have to manually reset them to restore internet connectivity.
2. When my PC goes to sleep (after about 15 Minutes) with NordVPN connected, I cannot seem to reach the NordVPN system daemon afterwards, or at least that's what commands like `nordvpn status` or `nordvpn connect` say - the existing connection doesn't seem to work anymore and only a restart seems to fix it.

Does anyone have similar problems or know how to fix any of them?

Comment: Need more details. What are the IPtables rules ? Can you post them along with your question ?

Comment: There aren't any rules. I cleared them after the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Reconnecting after suspend was fixed in update 3.8.6

The firewall problem you describe was fixed (for me) after update 3.8.8. Be sure to add required users to the nordvpn group after this update.

[Release Notes](https://nordvpn.com/blog/nordvpn-linux-release-notes/)